# Change string with sql UPDATE query

Tags: sql, sql-server

### Question

How could I change the following code from `SGC1-0001[` to `SGC1-001`.

The table is `stations` with column `code`. 
I need to use an update query, but not sure how to use it.

There are more records in the column that differ slightly but I should be able to work it out with an example to do one.

### Sample Data

I would like to do them in chunks though not one at a time.

```
SGC1-0001[
SGC1-0002[
..
SGC1-0019[
SGC1-0021[
SGC2-0001[
SGC2-0002[
..
SGC2-0016[
SGC2-0017[
SGC3-0003[
SGC3-0004[
...
SGC4-0018[
SGC4-0021[
SGC4-0022[
SGC4-0025[
SGC4-0029[
```

### Logic (pseudo code)

```
Delete first 0 and last [ from all
```

Comment: Can you provide other starting and desired ending values? From what you've provided, we don't know if the solution you need must be dynamic or not.

Comment: SGC4-0022[ should be replaced by ?

Comment: Thanks for adding additional example starting values. What would the desired ending value for `SGC4-0029[` be, for example?

Comment: Basically it will be string manipulation using SQL `REPLACE` and then whichever ones you want to do, use the `WHERE` clause to only do those.

Comment: @Dan Cundy:- see the my anwser, as it will delete the last '[' and first 0 after '-' from all records

Comment: @DanCundy Thanks for the further clarification. Do you want to remove the last character only if it's a '[', or always remove the last character regardless of what it is?

Comment: @Dan:- in OP sample data, all records have '[' at last, I don't think,asking this again n again will make sense now

Comment: I want to delete all ] in dataset

Comment: i have removed all the [ with drews answer

Comment: @Piyush The psuedo code is worded to remove the last [ character, your solution removes the final character regardless of what it is. This may or may not be a problem. I don't see the harm in clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're wanting to trim the last character of all records in that column as well as remove the leading 0, the following should do the trick:

```
UPDATE stations 
SET    code = REPLACE(LEFT(code, LEN(code) - 1), '-0', '-')
```

If you're just wanting to replace the leading 0, following should do:

```
UPDATE stations 
SET    code = REPLACE(code, '-0', '-')
```

Also, the following may be of interest:

[String Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx)

Comment: @DanCundy sure--revised!

Comment: And I have now removed the ] off them all so this query won't work any more. If you could explain it I could maybe edit it.

Comment: @DanCundy the REPLACE function 'Replaces all occurrences of a specified string value with another string value.' So in this case replace is replacing all occurances of '-0' with '-' in the string which was passe (in this case 'LEFT(code, LEN(code) - 1)', which is essentially the record without the trailing ']'. Hope this helps!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

Comment: That makes sense, I was getting confused thinking they were 'minus 0'. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Cool, and gotcha sir. Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Try This, Update query

Because all your code have '[' at last then you can use this query. it will delete the last `'['` and first 0 after `'-'` from all records

```
UPDATE stations
SET  CODE = LEFT(replace(code,right(code,1),''),4) + '-'+
            RIGHT(RIGHT(replace(code,right(code,1),''),4),3)
```

It will replace 
`SGC1-0029[` to `SGC1-029` AND
`SGC1-0001[` to `SGC1-001`

Better to refer some sql basic [tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)